# Want to show input box on selecting different option from drop down list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ng-if to show and hide the input box and while doing so whenever i refresh my page then the input appears automatically and on selecting the options it is getting hide. I have attached my code.Any lead will be appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

```
 <select id="notifyBy" 
         style="border:none" 
         class="formtext1 inputimg" 
         ng-model="singleSelect">

     <option  value="option1">E-mail</option>
     <option value="option2">Instant Message</option>
     <option value="option3">Telephone</option>
     <option value="option4">None</option>

</select>

<input placeholder="Please enter phone number" 
       class="formtext1" 
       ng-if ="singleSelect === Telephone"></input>
```

Comment: I think it should be `ng-if ="singleSelect === 'Telephone'"` that is if you don't have a variable `Telephone` in your scope.

Comment: In your controller initialize `$scope.singleSelect = ''` and on selection from dropdown do `$scope.singleSelect  = 'Telephone'`.

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: @psycho I am not getting you Can u please elaborate what i have to do in controller :)

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. But you should initialise your variables with `$scope` in your controller, before binding them in `view/DOM`.

Comment: Oh Okay !! Now I got it . And yes it's working :) Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation :** Instead of comparing with the Option text compare it with the ng-model value **.**

Use this `ng-if="singleSelect == 'option3'"` instead of `ng-if="singleSelect == 'Telephone'"`

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <select id="notifyBy" 
         style="border:none" 
         class="formtext1 inputimg" 
         ng-model="singleSelect">
     <option  value="option1">E-mail</option>
     <option value="option2">Instant Message</option>
     <option value="option3">Telephone</option>
     <option value="option4">None</option>
</select>
<input ng-show="singleSelect == 'option3'" placeholder="Please enter phone number" ng-model="phonenumber"
       class="formtext1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you singleSelect model will have value of option select not the text, so you can not test singleSelect === Telephone, you need to test singleSelect === option3

Comment: do console.log($scope.singleSelect) at the end of controller. maybe on refresh singleSelect and see what value do you have there. Or try switch to ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your ng-model

```
<select  id="notifyBy" 
        style="border:none" 
        class="formtext1 inputimg" 
        ng-model="singleSelect"  
        ng-init="singleSelect = ''">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="notifyBy"   
        style="border:none" 
        class="formtext1 inputimg" 
        ng-model="singleSelect">

          <option  value="option1">E-mail</option>
          <option value="option2">Instant Message</option>
          <option value="option3">Telephone</option>
          <option value="option4">None</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input placeholder="Please enter phone number" 
       class="formtext1" 
       ng-if="singleSelect === 'option3'"></input>
```